# Android Retrofit Upload picture with text to PHP server

Tags: php, android, mysqli, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to create a system, where I can upload profile info like name, email, password & profile picture, where the user can select picture from gallery or camera. Im trying to use Retrofit with a PHP Server and MySQL database.

The problem is that, my code is working with images only or text only(name, email, password), I can't seem to get it to work with both:

Here's my code: Interface Class

```
 @POST("addProfile.php")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<ServerResponse> addProfile(
        @Field("name") String name,
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password,
        @Field("picTitle") String picTitle,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part picFile

);
```

AppConfig class:

```
public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

uploadToPHPServer method:

```
private void uploadToServer(String name, String email, String password,String picTitle) {

    File file = new File(postPath);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("*/*")
            , file);

    MultipartBody.Part fileToSend = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picPath", file.getName(), requestBody);
    //picTitle = file.getName();

    //making api call
    ApiConfig api = AppConfig.getClient().create(ApiConfig.class);
    Call<ServerResponse> addingProfile = api.addProfile(name, email, password, picTitle, fileToSend);

    addingProfile.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()){

                Toast.makeText(CaptureDetails.this,"Profile upload successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(CaptureDetails.this,response.body().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(CaptureDetails.this,t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


}
```

I'm getting the following error when i try to upload:

```
2019-03-26 16:58:21.929 11828-11828/zw.co.vokers.vinceg.vokers E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: zw.co.vokers.vinceg.vokers, PID: 11828
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Part parameters can only be used with multipart encoding. (parameter #7)
    for method ApiConfig.addEntry
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:752)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:743)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:761)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:592)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:336)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:204)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
    at $Proxy0.addEntry(Unknown Source)
    at zw.co.vokers.vinceg.vokers.activities.CaptureDetails.uploadToServer(CaptureDetails.java:578)
    at zw.co.vokers.vinceg.vokers.activities.CaptureDetails.access$400(CaptureDetails.java:78)
    at zw.co.vokers.vinceg.vokers.activities.CaptureDetails$1.onClick(CaptureDetails.java:189)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I get the `@Part parameters can only be used with multipart encoding.` part, but if I try to change that I get to add the @MultiPart annotation to the Interface class it gives me vice-versa error.

I was following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mtO24yqVk0) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKxLgEfY49A), when I got stuck...I cant seem to find a tutorial or a similar question on Stack.

Any help, or direction offered is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, the error was you're trying to use `FormurlEncoded`

```
@POST("addProfile.php")
@Multipart
Call<ServerResponse> addProfile(
    @Part ("name") String name,
    @Part ("email") String email,
    @Part ("password") String password,
    @Part ("picTitle") String picTitle,
    @Part MultipartBody.Part picFile
);
```

Comment: Thanks this sorted it